# Windows azure Pack Website

Tags: windows, azure, web, pack

I'm going to install Windows Azure Pack Website on my machine, but I've got this error: `Signature verification failed on download file....`

This is my end-line of log file:

```
[0E48:07DC][2015-05-07T19:43:37]: [Websites]: Downloaded file: 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/E/05E8D1D8-70CF-45F5-B264-621877362BB9/webpi/installers/SQLCLRTypes_Only_x64_11_0/7CE5C2888C150F7F3F31DDE4DD4831E6B4A50E97/SQLSysClrTypes.msi' to location 'C:\HostingOfflineFeed\installers\SQLCLRTypes_Only_x64_11_0\721EE22B542110D03348E9491F3D7BDFA24C78DB\SQLSysClrTypes.msi'
[0E48:07DC][2015-05-07T19:43:37]: [Websites]: Signature verification failed on downloaded file. URL: http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/E/05E8D1D8-70CF-45F5-B264-621877362BB9/webpi/installers/SQLCLRTypes_Only_x64_11_0/7CE5C2888C150F7F3F31DDE4DD4831E6B4A50E97/SQLSysClrTypes.msi. File location: C:\HostingOfflineFeed\installers\SQLCLRTypes_Only_x64_11_0\721EE22B542110D03348E9491F3D7BDFA24C78DB\SQLSysClrTypes.msi.. Line 0
[0E48:07DC][2015-05-07T19:43:37]: [Websites]: Step Offline products has completed with error.
```

Comment: Hi, I suggest you to reinstall it since it shows you an download error  or you can go to [Windows Azure Training Kit](http://windowsazure-trainingkit.github.io) and install it. If the error still arise, please post your log here.

Comment: not yet solved...., it's still error

Answer (score 0):

**Try installing the package before the installation.
Use Web Platform Installer and search for "SQL CLR Types"
Install the package on the machine and then try starting the installation.**

I think something is wrong with that package version the installer is trying to install.

Please revert back if it fixed you issue,

**Happy to help!
-CB**

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by

1. installing **SQL Server CLR** Type
2. running Windows Update.

Dunno which one did the fix, but I wish these info can help others.